# Replace a isNull with If Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, isnull

I have a stored procedure where it can return no row, in that case I would like to put 'Other' as a value.
My procedure set the values of my column '@col', I tried to use ISNULL but it is wrong

```
update cal
set '+@col+' = isnull(p.par_name, ''Other'')
from #CALENDAR cal
inner join #WEBSITES w on w.par_id = cal.par_id and
    (
        w.bur_id = cal.bur_id
        or
        (w.date = cal.Date or (w.[date] is null and cal.Date is null))
    )
left join partner p on p.par_id = isnull(w.par_id,-1) AND tpa_id = 3 -- partner de type advertiser
where website_id ='+convert(varchar(3), @wid)
```

I tried to put a IF EXIST like so, it didn't work :

```
update cal
set '+@col+' = if exists (p.par_name
from #CALENDAR cal
inner join #WEBSITES w on w.par_id = cal.par_id and
    (
        w.bur_id = cal.bur_id
        or
        (w.date = cal.Date or (w.[date] is null and cal.Date is null))
    )
left join partner p on p.par_id = isnull(w.par_id,-1) AND tpa_id = 3 -- partner de type advertiser
where website_id ='+convert(varchar(3), @wid)+') else ''Other'' '
```

To simplify the query what i do is (mix sql and c#):

```
if(w.par_id = null)
 select p.par_name from partner p where p.par_id = -1 <= will return nothing, an empty row
THEN if(p.par_name is EMPTY) THEN p.par_name='Other'
```

Which will return no row, in that case I want to put 'Other'

Comment: What kind of syntax is `set '+@col+'`?

Comment: For setting value to variable You can use syntax like this set @col = 'value'. Your code do another things

Comment: When you say "It is wrong", what do you mean? Is the query throwing an error, or are you getting the wrong result?

Comment: @GordonLinoff My syntax is correct I just didn't put the full query, I edited  :) It was an update

Comment: @Aidan The value won't be null, the query will just return nothing, which is not "NULL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options you can use:

1. @@ROWCOUNT: Do your regular select and aftwards check for the value of `@@ROWCOUNT`, if it's `0` then the previous statement returned 0 rows, so you can do an additional `SELECT` with your hard-coded value.

   ```
   SELECT p.par_name
   FROM #CALENDAR
   WHERE --...

   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
   BEGIN
       SELECT 'Other' AS par_name
   END
   ```
2. Validate your result set in your C# code. Check if the result set has 0 rows, then generate your value directly in C#.
3. Do an `LEFT JOIN` with a 1 row generated table against your result set.

   ```
   SELECT
       ISNULL(X.par_name, G.par_name) AS par_name
   FROM
       (VALUES ('Other')) AS G(par_name)
       LEFT JOIN (

           SELECT
               p.par_name
           from 
               #CALENDAR cal
               inner join #WEBSITES w on w.par_id = cal.par_id and
                   (
                       w.bur_id = cal.bur_id
                       or
                       (w.date = cal.Date or (w.[date] is null and cal.Date is null))
                   )
               left join partner p on p.par_id = isnull(w.par_id,-1) AND tpa_id = 3 -- partner de type advertiser
           where 
               website_id = '+convert(varchar(3), @wid)'
       ) 
       AS X ON G.par_name = X.par_name
   ```

Don't use an `EXISTS` because you will be forced to duplicate your query, causing additional maintainance.

Comment: On your last proposition, what are X and G ? The same table partner (see my left join)?

Comment: @Benoît `G` is a generated table with the value `'Other'`, you can see it being aliased at `(VALUES ('Other')) AS G(par_name)`, while `X` is your whole query, which was enclosed in parenthesis and aliased at the last line.

Answer (score 1):

The function `isnull(p.par_name, ''Other'')` only works if the select returns 1 row and in that row the column `par_name` is `NULL`.

To workaround this, first set the variable name in case there is no rows in your select and then do the select. Something like this...

```
-- set value in case no rows are found
set @col = 'Other'

-- if a row is found and there is a null, set the value again to Other
select @col = isnull(p.par_name, 'Other')
from #CALENDAR cal
inner join #WEBSITES w on w.par_id = cal.par_id and
    (
        w.bur_id = cal.bur_id
        or
        (w.date = cal.Date or (w.[date] is null and cal.Date is null))
    )
left join partner p on p.par_id = isnull(w.par_id,-1) AND tpa_id = 3 -- partner de type advertiser
where website_id ='+convert(varchar(3), @wid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE()` function. The `COALESCE()` function returns the first non-null expression in a list. below is the syntax:

```
COALESCE(expr1, expr2, ...., expr_n)
```

expr1, expr2, expr_n - The expressions/col/value to test